# Use computed column or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, calculated-columns

I have a table with a few columns that are used as `datetime` stamps. The table contains the following columns

```
UpDate      datetime
SearchDate  datetime
ExpDate     dateadd(hour,24,UpDate)
Active      nvarchar(5)
```

When the `UpDate` column is updated by the daily import the computed column `ExpDate` will be updated with the time + 24 hours. I would like the `Active` column to indicate `'Y'` when the current datetime is less than the `ExpDate` and `'N'` when the current datetime is equal to or more than the `ExpDate`.

I thought of just using a stored procedure to run indefinitely to check this and update as needed but that does not make sense to do and would like to know if anyone has any other suggestions on how to do this. For example if I can use that as a computed column as well based on an IF statement query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to persist the calculation of `ExpDate` and `Active` I think you should do the calculation in your queries against the your table.

Something like this:

```
select [UpDate],
       SearchDate,
       dateadd(hour, 24, SearchDate) as ExpDate,
       case when getdate() >= dateadd(hour, 24, SearchDate)
         then 'N' 
         else 'Y' 
       end as Active
from YourTable
```

If you want computed columns your DDL would look like this:

```
create table YourTable
(
  [UpDate] datetime,
  SearchDate datetime,
  ExpDate as dateadd(hour, 24, SearchDate),
  Active as case when getdate() >= dateadd(hour, 24, SearchDate)
              then 'N' 
              else 'Y' 
            end
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. If I understand correctly, you mean when I query the table for the records that I want where ExpDate has not yet been reached, then set Active = Y and for all others set to N?

Comment: I mean that you calculate both ExpDate and Active at the time when you execute the query. Not to store anywhere or update anything, just to return the values to your client for the query that is currently executed.